# Bug in Entity Framework 4.3 code first - index already exists

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3

Everything worked fine in previous versions but now in 4.3 I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The operation failed because an index or
>   statistics with name 'IX_Id' already exists on table 'Users'.

---

The User table has an Id property and is the primary key but I'm not using code or attributes anywhere else to create an additional index??

User Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Settings Settings { get; set; } /* 1-1 */

    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; } /* 1-1 */
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; } /* 1-1 */


}
```

It's failing here in my  OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)

```
          modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.Settings).WithRequiredDependent();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.Profile).WithRequiredDependent();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.Account).WithRequiredDependent();
```

Update: just fixed it by using WithRequiredPrincipal instead of WithRequiredDependent. Not sure why this is different in 4.3

Comment: Can you show us your code for the User model?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. However .WithRequired(), .WithRequiredPrincipal(), and .WithRequiredDependent() all fail.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438219/index-already-exists-error-in-ef-4-3-code-first-with-data-annotations

Comment: It may be a duplicate but it's hard to predict what questions might be asked in May when you post them in February.

Comment: And still a bug in EF 5.0 RTM.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in EF 4.3. It will be fixed in EF5 RTM. For more information including a workaround see this question: [Unhandled Exception after Upgrading to Entity Framework 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441924/unhandled-exception-after-upgrading-to-entity-framework-4-3-1)