# Index already exists error in EF 4.3 Code First with Data Annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, entity-framework-4.3

I'm trying to create a billing database with Entity Framework 4.3 using Code First with Data Annotations, and I'm getting an error every time I try to create my database. Here are the objects that I'm dealing with:

```
public class ClientBase
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ClientContactName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ClientContactEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PropertyBase> Communities { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyBase
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    [Required, EnumDataType(typeof(BillingFrequency))]
    public BillingFrequency PropertyBillingFrequency { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public string PropertyStreet { get; set; }

    public string PropertyCity { get; set; }

    public string PropertyState { get; set; }

    public int PropertyZipCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ClientBase Client { get; set; }
}
```

No matter what I try to do, I always get this error:

```
The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_ClientID' already exists on table 'Property'.
```

I've seen solutions to this question with the Fluent API, but I haven't found one for Data Annotations.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

EDIT: Here is the code in the DbContext:

```
public DbSet<ClientBase> ClientBases { get; set; }
public DbSet<PropertyBase> PropertyBases { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: It all works for me.  I don't understand where *table 'Property'* is coming from in this configuration.

Comment: Yikes! I forgot to put [Table("Property")] over the PropertyBase class.

Comment: Could there be a trigger running on the SQL server that created the Index?  I have no idea where it (even the first one) would be coming from.

Comment: I guess you did, but have you tried making sure you have nothing in the Db to begin with - and make sure you know where it 'goes' (what's your config for connection, defaultConnectionFactory etc.), where do you get errors? using migrations, or tried w/ it? How do you call the context, initialize etc. Try making a new project, new connection etc., i.e. start from scratch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. It turned out that I had forgotten that there was another class that I had made that had a Foreign Key relationship to ClientBase. I forgot to bring that into ClientBase as a virtual property and Entity Framework was not happy with me. When I included it, it worked perfectly.

Thank you both for your help!