# Error "operation failed because an index or statistics with name X already exists on table Y

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a website to **Azure Web Apps**. IDE: **Visual Studio 2015/U3**.

Site: **ASP.NET MVC 4** website. I try to deploy the site to Azure Web App through VS using **Publish**.

Error in browser:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> *The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_OwnerId' already exists on table 'dbo.Auctions'.*
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_OwnerId'
>   already exists on table 'dbo.Auctions'.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---

**Stack Trace:**

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_OwnerId' already exists on table 'dbo.Auctions'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2442634
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5766568
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +948
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +286
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +286
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +356
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +103
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +109
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +83
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +65
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +155
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +346
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection) +509
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e() +19
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction) +194
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto) +828
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading) +559
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +403
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +445
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +422
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
   System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +108
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +357
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +198
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +53
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) +146
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector) +89
   OnlineAuction.Controllers.HomeController.Index(Int32 CategoryId, String SearchKeyword) in C:\Users\Chico\Desktop\DIPLOMA PROJECT\DIPLOMA PROJECT\Проект\задав вопрос о оунерАди\delete — копия\OnlineDonors\Controllers\HomeController.cs:26
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765121
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

---

I looked at this post:
[Unhandled Exception after Upgrading to Entity Framework 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441924/unhandled-exception-after-upgrading-to-entity-framework-4-3-1)

I tried to remove duplicates on my `Auctions` table. 
This is my `Auctions` and `Users` tables creation in `Up()` method of `InitialCreate` class:

```
public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Auctions",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Title = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 160),
                    Description = c.String(nullable: false),
                    CurrentPrice = c.Double(nullable: false),
                    StartTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    EndTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    OwnerId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    WinningBidId = c.Int(),
                    CategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.OwnerId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Bids", t => t.WinningBidId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.CategoryId)
            .Index(t => t.OwnerId)
            .Index(t => t.WinningBidId)
            .Index(t => t.CategoryId);                   
     }
 }
```

---

At first I removed this line:

```
 .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.OwnerId)
```

And redeployed the site. Still the same error.

Then I removed `.Index(t => t.OwnerId)` from `Auctions` table creation.
The same error occurs.

---

**Additional info:**

In `Application_Start()` method of **Global.asax** I have this line:

```
 System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AuctionDataContext, Configuration>());
```

In `<configSections>` of **Web.config**:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

My initializations are in `Configuration` class:

```
   public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<OnlineAuction.Models.Entities.AuctionDataContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(AuctionDataContext context)
        { 
            ***All my initializations go here 
        }
    }
```

---

**Question:** How to fix it?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the ForeignKeyIndexConvention Code First convention could cause indexes to be created for the columns of any foreign key in the model. You could try to remove this convention on DbContext.OnModelCreating Method.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //your code  

    //remove ForeignKeyIndexConvention  
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>();
}
```